# How to include "&" in variable label for LaTeX output using esttab?

Tags: latex, stata

I am trying to export some regression tables from Stata to `LaTeX`.

The problem is that I want to display variable labels in the table but some of my labels contain the `&` character. As such, when I use the *community-contributed* command `esttab` to export to `LaTeX` and then try to compile, I get an error because the `Texmaker` thinks `&` should indicate an extra column.

Below is my Stata code:

```
esttab results1 results2 using "$repodir/output/tables/tract_xregs.tex", ///
       se noconstant label star(* 0.10 ** 0.05 *** 0.01) replace  ///
       nonotes compress nomtitles booktabs ///
       s(modelsample modelobs, label("Sample" "N")) 

esttab sumstats1 using "$repodir/output/tables/tract_sumstats.tex", booktabs label ///
       nonumbers cells("mean p50 min max sd") replace
```

How can I include the `&` character in my variable label without getting an error when compiling it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is important that you always provide an example with both data and code that reproduces your problem. Please read the [Stata tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info) for advice on how to ask Stata-related questions on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following example using Stata' toy `auto` dataset, which reproduces your problem:

```
sysuse auto, clear
estimates clear

label variable weight "One & Two"

regress price weight
estimates store ols

esttab ols, label tex

{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{c}}
\hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price}\\
\hline
One & Two           &       2.044\sym{***}\\
                    &      (5.42)         \\
[1em]
Constant            &      -6.707         \\
                    &     (-0.01)         \\
\hline
Observations        &          74         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
}
```

You need to include a `\` before the `&` in the variable label as follows:

```
label variable weight "One \& Two"

esttab ols, label tex

{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{c}}
\hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price}\\
\hline
One \& Two          &       2.044\sym{***}\\
                    &      (5.42)         \\
[1em]
Constant            &      -6.707         \\
                    &     (-0.01)         \\
\hline
Observations        &          74         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
}
```

The former produces an error, while the latter compiles fine.